# mv in for loop : “when moving multiple files last argument must be a directory”

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, rename

I try to rename  few files, omitting the first n characters. In fact I want to remove the `[ www.blabla.com ]` prefix (18 chars).

I'm on windows, using bash command on Git-bash.

I've tried this command :

```
for f in *blabla*; do 
    mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's/^...................//');
done
```

But I've the error : "when moving multiple files last argument must be a directory". But my inderstanding is that I already do the mv one by one

Comment: Double quotes missing.

Comment: You could use the `-t` option: `mv -t dirname *blabla*`

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/1005953 -- please don't post the same question to multiple sites.

Comment: @glennjackman indeed, I thought about superuser first but SO is faster so I will continue to post here. Good note